# Building Math-Pari-2.010709 for Liinux

Tags: linux, perl, pari

I have downloaded Math-Pari-2.010709.tar.gz from

```
http://search.cpan.org/~ilyaz/Math-Pari-2.010709/Pari.pm
```

and trying to install the pari library on Linux OS. Below are the details of my OS.

```
LSB_VERSION="core-2.0-noarch:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-noarch:core-2.0-x86_64:core-3.2-x86_64:core-4.0-x86_64"
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11
PATCHLEVEL = 3
```

I extracted the zip file and did perl Makefile.PL. When I am trying to run the make test, its throwing me below errors. Please help.I am installing perl for the first time so this may sound a silly question.

```
cd libPARI && make LIBPERL_A="libperl.a" LINKTYPE="dynamic" OPTIMIZE="-O2" PREFIX="/home/fd1123/localperl" PASTHRU_DEFINE="" PASTHRU_INC=""
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/fd1123/build/Math-Pari-2.010709/libPARI'
cc -c  -I ../../pari-2.7.1/src -I../../pari-2.7.1/src/headers -I../../pari-2.7.1/src/graph -I. -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O2   -DVERSION=\"\" -DXS_VERSION=\"\" -fPIC -Derr=pari_err -DASMINLINE -DGCC_INLINE -DDYNAMIC_PLOTTING -o rootpol.o ../../pari-2.7.1/src/basemath/rootpol.c
In file included from ../../pari-2.7.1/src/basemath/rootpol.c:20:
../../pari-2.7.1/src/headers/pari.h:56:20: error: parimt.h: No such file or directory
../../pari-2.7.1/src/headers/pari.h:58:21: error: mpinl.h: No such file or directory
../../pari-2.7.1/src/basemath/rootpol.c: In function ‘mydbllog2i’:
../../pari-2.7.1/src/basemath/rootpol.c:378: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
../../pari-2.7.1/src/basemath/rootpol.c:381: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘int’)
make[1]: *** [rootpol.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/fd1123/build/Math-Pari-2.010709/libPARI'
make: *** [libPARI/libPARI.a] Error 2
```

I downloaded the Pari library from http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/download.html and trying to install. Now getting error. Pls check.

```
Making gp in Olinux-x86_64
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/fd1123/sachin_build/pari-2.7.1/Olinux-x86_64'
"/usr/lib/qt3"/bin/moc -o plotQt.moc.cpp ../src/graph/plotQt.c && g++ -c -I. -I../src/headers -D__FANCY_WIN__ -I"/usr/lib/qt3"/include -O3 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -fomit-frame-pointer    -o plotQt.o ../src/graph/plotQt.c
```

> ```
> /bin/sh: /usr/lib/qt3/bin/moc: No such file or directory
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Those errors are generally due to not being able to find the headers for the library its linking to. From https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Pari:

> PARI Starting from version 2.0, this module comes without a PARI
>   library included. For the source of PARI library see
>   ftp://megrez.math.u-bordeaux.fr/pub/pari.

You need to download the library so that the module can compile against it.

Answer (score 0):

moc is the "Meta Object Compiler" from qt.  Install a package called libqt4-devel or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Spent a bunch of time on this, trying to make it find missing libs, symbols, defines, etc.  Eventually determined that the latest version of the PARI library supported by the CPAN module is pari-2.1.7  Current version of the PARI libary is pari-2.7.4, and is incompatible.